# Python 3.X Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock issue

Tags: python

Hello i am new to coding but i have been stuck on a code for very long and can't seem to find the answer here on stackoverflow.

Whatever i do the answer ends up with the first print of Player 1 wins: Player One wins, Rock beats Scissors.

```
player1 = input("Player One do you want Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?")
player2 = input("Player Two do you want Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?")
print(player1)
print(player2)

rock = 1
paper = 2
scissors = 3
lizard = 4
spock = 5

#Tie

if (player1 == player2):
print("It's a tie.")

#Player 1 wins

elif (player1 == 1, player2 == 3):
    print("Player One wins, Rock beats Scissors.")
elif (player1 == 1, player2 == 4):
    print("Player One wins, Rock beats Lizard.")
elif (player1 == 2, player2 == 1):
    print("Player One wins, Paper beats Rock.")
elif (player1 == 2, player2 == 5):
    print("Player One wins, Paper beats Spock.")
elif (player1 == 3, player2 == 2):
    print("Player One wins, Scissors beats Paper.")
elif (player1 == 3, player2 == 4):
    print("Player One wins, Scissors beats Lizard.")
elif (player1 == 4, player2 == 2):
    print("Player One wins, Lizard beats Paper.")
elif (player1 == 4, player2 == 5):
    print("Player One wins, Lizard beats Spock.")
elif (player1 == 5, player2 == 3):
    print("Player One wins, Spock beats Scissors.")
elif (player1 == 5 , player2 == 1):
    print("Player One wins, Spock beats Rock.")

#Player 2 wins       

elif (player2 == 1, player1 == 3):
    print("Player Two wins, Rock beats Scissors.")
elif (player2 == 1, player1 == 4):
    print("Player Two wins, Rock beats Lizard.")
elif (player2 == 2, player1 == 1):
    print("Player Two wins, Paper beats Rock.")
elif (player2 == 2, player1 == 5):
    print("Player Two wins, Paper beats Spock.")
elif (player2 == 3, player1 == 2):
    print("Player Two wins, Scissors beats Paper.")
elif (player2 == 3, player1 == 4):
    print("Player Two wins, Scissors beats Lizard.")
elif (player2 == 4, player1 == 2):
    print("Player Two wins, Lizard beats Paper.")
elif (player2 == 4, player1 == 5):
    print("Player Two wins, Lizard beats Spock.")
elif (player2 == 5, player1 == 3):
    print("Player Two wins, Spock beats Scissors.")
elif (player2 == 5 , player1 == 1):
    print("Player Two wins, Spock beats Rock.")
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not properly constructing your conditions.

```
elif (player1 == 1, player2 == 3)
```

This creates a `tuple` and then checks it for truthiness, which always succeeds, because that `tuple` is not empty. You need to use the logical operator `and`:

```
elif player1 == 1 and player2 == 3
```

This will check whether both of those conditions are true. Do this for all similar instances in your code.

Additionally, it's unclear what you are expecting from the user here:

```
player1 = input("Player One do you want Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?")
player2 = input("Player Two do you want Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?")
print(player1)
print(player2)

rock = 1
paper = 2
scissors = 3
lizard = 4
spock = 5
```

It looks like the user is supposed to enter something like `Rock`, and then you expect the `rock = 1` line to convert `'Rock'` to `1`. It does not work that way. The most basic way to do this is with another `if..elif` block, but a dictionary would be better:

```
player1 = input("Player One do you want Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?")
player2 = input("Player Two do you want Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?")
print(player1)
print(player2)

d = {'Rock':1, 'Paper':2, 'Scissors':3, 'Lizard':4, 'Spock':5}

player1 = d.get(player1)
player2 = d.get(player2)
```

Comment: The colon in your solution is missing- it should be `elif player1 == 1 and player2 == 3:` this might confuse beginners, as @Omar states he is.

Comment: @Maurice - I wasn't quoting a complete line.

Comment: Hello, thankyou so much for your answer, i didn't know you could use 'and' and 'd'. Unfortunaly now when i try to do any combination it shows absolutely nothing except the user input (like 1,2,3,4).

Comment: @Omar - Have the user enter the actual move they want to make, like `Rock` or `Lizard`.

Answer (score 0):

While TigerHawk covered your condiction, you also have to cast your inputs to ints.

```
player1 = int(player1)
player2 = int(player2)
```

Right now you are comparing a str (your input) to an int (`player == 1`). Which won't yield what you want.

```
player1 == 1      #fails right now since it's like asking "1" == 1 which fails.
int(player1) == 1 # passes since it's asking 1 == 1.
```

Also your `print("It's a tie.")` is indented wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunaly even when i do this i have the same problem now with TigerHawk his solution: The only output i get is the users input like 1,2,3,4 unless i do the Tie solution which works...

Comment: Also your `print("It's a tie.")` is indented wrong. @Omar you might want to edit your code in your question.

Comment: I just did fix that but as i mentioned above the problem is still here.

Comment: I meant edit your question so we can see what you changed. Telling us what you may have done isn't helpful. @Omar